# What should I use for service location in erlang?

Tags: erlang

I'm writing my first distributed erlang application, and I notice that I have to know the node on which I have my "service" up. How can I send requests to my service without knowing on which node it is running?

Basically I want to do something like this:

```
ReferenceToTheServiceProcess = locate(my_service).
ReferenceToTheServiceProcess ! {request, Stuff}.
```

Or something else to the equivalent effect (loose coupling).

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could register your service process with a global name, for example using [`gproc`](https://github.com/uwiger/gproc). That way you don't have to know which node your service currently resides on, and your could would pretty much look like you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

You can register the process using the [global](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/global.html) module.
From your service process call:

```
global:register_name(my_service, self()).
```

To send a message to the globally registered process call:

```
Pid = global:whereis_name(my_service),
Pid ! {request, Stuff}.
```

or call:

```
global:send(my_service, {request, Stuff}).
```

The registration functionality is atomic.
If the service process terminates or the node goes down, the name will be globally unregistered.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you still want local registration of process you could write something like:

```
 where_is_service(Service) ->
     lists:filter(fun(X) -> X =/= undefined end, [rpc:call(Node, erlang, whereis, [Service]) || Node <- [node() | nodes()]]).
```

This function will give back as result the pid of the processes referred locally (on the nodes) as `Service`

After this if you want just the first process running use the list returned by the function:

```
send_msg_to_service(Service,Message) ->
     case where_is_service(Service) of
        [APid | _] -> APid ! Message, ok;
        []         -> {error, service_not_running}
     end.
```

Hope this helps!